# Merging files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: linux, csv, google-bigquery, gzip, google-cloud-storage

I exported results from a Google BigQuery query into Cloud Storage as a gzipped csv. Since the result is around 28GB it appears as multiple files (of 53MB) in the Cloud Storage. I could download them to my local machine using gsutil. How can I merge all these into one file like result.csv.gz in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. You just have to merge it like any other file in linux.

```
cat file_* > result.csv.gz
```